# Weird margin Angular2 custom component (Ionic2)

Tags: css, angular, sass, ionic2

Since I'm using Ionic2 RC0 and Angular2 Final, when I create custom components, those components creates a margin and I don#t know how to remove it and if this is a Ionic or Angular problem. That is the first time I'm having this issue, before the update was not like that (I guess).

See image:

[image]

The custom component is the one with black border it's just a wrapper and has no style. There are also no margins and no paddings.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: In Chrome open up developers console, press Ctrl + Shift + C, (inspect element) there you can exactly see what's causing it.

Comment: I did it already...I can not find what is causing the issue. As I said - no margin and padding anywhere for this element and it's children

Comment: Can you recreate this in a plunkr?

Comment: Check the inner elements, they can have a margin or padding too which can cause behavior like this.